# Why the this question is not eligible for being a wiki?

Tags: discussion

I write in the response to the comments of moderator @chl on this queston: [Methods for multiple comparisons correction with bootstrap for multiple glm models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41906/methods-for-multiple-comparisons-correction-with-bootstrap-for-multiple-glm-mode#comment82644_41906)

Please tell me, why it is not apropriate as a Wiki? My question is quite broad (without simple answer) and I can't find any resource on the web on this topic, so I believe it might be in public interest to have it here instead on my personal blog.

Comment: It appears to me that @chl is saying that it is not clear what is being asked in your post. Maybe you just need to edit your post and state the question clearly after giving some context. Typically people in this site introduce the problem and then write in bold **My question is: ...**

Comment: I explained my position in my multiple comments beneath your question. I'll wait for other reactions/suggestions.

Comment: I agree with @chl: What question? Even if that thread can be reformulated as a question, I urge you to rethink the strategy of posting three separate answers: this leads to a fragmentation and lack of unity that make the thread of less potential use to readers.

Comment: @whuber, chi, procrastinator. No problem, you've got it. Just give me one-two days. If I have any technical problems (like deleting answers which I already ceded to wiki) I'll turn to you.

Comment: @chi I've made it into a question. Now, I already marked two answers as Wiki. Is there any way of undoing it?

Comment: Adam, what I proposed was to merge your three answers into a single reply. I don't think the fact they've been made CW really matters in this case. Just copy/paste and delete two of the three replies. A moderator will remove the CW status of the remaining one if you like.

Comment: @chi ok. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have merged your three answers and removed CW status.

Comment: @chi Thank you. Eventually I forgot to do this... Thanks again.

Comment: Related: [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To summarize:** the thread in question began life as a statement followed by three separate answers.  In response to comments here, it has been converted into a question plus one answer divided into three clear sections.

The initial issue was that threads on SE need to maintain the standard question-answer format, even when they are used as a blog-like medium of exposition.  That issue is independent of the CW status.  It seems to me that the OP is correct in suggesting that his thread be given CW status, because he maintains that there are likely many useful answers, not limited to the three he has already provided, and that he hopes the thread can (over time) become a compendium of related solutions.